# Iteration over a list not working how I'd imagine. Why?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, audio

Programming newb here trying to work with audio for the first time (wanting to make a program that slices a wave file at a certain decibel level)

```
wf = wave.open('test.wav', 'r')

wfArraydB = []

for i in range(0, wf.getnframes()): # For every frame/sample, this loop is performed.
    waveData = wf.readframes(1) # Can only do 1 frame because struct.unpack can only do 1 frame
    data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData) # Converts wave data from hexadecimal
    a = wf.tell() # Returns the frame that the file pointer is at
    cf = copysign(data[0], 1) # Converts wave data
    #print("data[0]: %d, cf: %d, cf/32767: %d" % (data[0], cf, cf/32767))
    if data[0] != 0: # Eliminates a math module error if the wave sample value is 0
        b = 20 * log10(cf/32767) # Converts non-hexadecimal wave data to dB format
    else:
        b = -90
    #print("frame %d: %d dB" % (a, b))
    wfArraydB.append(int(b))


acceptableLvl = []
acceptableLvlPre = []
threshold = -40

for i in range(0, len(wfArraydB)): 
    if wfArraydB[i] > threshold:
        acceptableLvlPre.append(i)

    if wfArraydB[i] < threshold: 
        if len(acceptableLvlPre) > 4410: # If sequence of frames over -40 is longer than 4410 samples or 0.1s
            acceptableLvl.append(acceptableLvlPre) # Stores frames in which there is sufficiently loud sound
            acceptableLvlPre[:] = [] # Remove all contents from pre-list (using slice assignment)

print(acceptableLvl)
```

When I do a print(acceptableLvl) I'm expecting to see a list of lists, which have the two requirements: 1. All values are over -40 (dB, working with an audio file), and 2. all the lists have a length longer than 4410 samples (0.1 seconds).

Instead the list that is returning contains 13 repititions of the same list that contains only 12 index values (which are all near the end of the ~2 second sound file @ 44,100 hz)

```
[[85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039], [85368, 87027, 87028, 87029, 87030, 87031, 87032, 87035, 87036, 87037, 87038, 87039]]
```

Not really understanding why as it should be returning values much more before 80,000 samples as well, since there is loudness in the audio file at the beginning and middle too (10,000 to 50,000 samples)

Any help with my syntax or whatever else would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: why are you using `acceptableLvlPre[:] = []`?

Comment: not sure actually I just thought it would do the same thing as `acceptableLvlPre = []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in Python are mutable. Your `acceptableLvl` has 13 links to the same list instance `acceptableLvlPre`. You modify `acceptableLvlPre`, so all the copies are modified.

The solution is simple: replace `acceptableLvlPre[:] = []` with `acceptableLvlPre = []`. Then a new list will be created, and all will be fine.